# TinyMCE only initializes once, and then it calls it quits after that

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using the Ruby on Rails TinyMCE gem and I'm simply trying to have it initialize on every page load, considering there's a great amount of textboxes that uses TinyMCE class.

Here's my apps/assets/javascripts/application.js file:

```
var ready;

ready = function(){
  tinyMCE.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    toolbar: ["styleselect | undo redo | bold italic underline | bullist | outdent indent"],
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false,
    style_formats: [{"title":"Headers","items":[{"title":"Header 1","format":"h1"},{"title":"Header 2","format":"h2"},{"title":"Header 3","format":"h3"}]},{"title":"Inline","items":[{"title":"Bold","icon":"bold","format":"bold"},{"title":"Italic","icon":"italic","format":"italic"},{"title":"Underline","icon":"underline","format":"underline"},{"title":"Code","icon":"code","format":"code"}]}],
    content_css: "/assets/tinymce.css"
  });

};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

I can throw in an alert('test'); in the function and it runs every time I load a new page, but why won't TinyMCE initialize every time either? It only works when I refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

I have also used this TinyMCE editor in my app. But i didn't faced this problem. May be it takes time to load tinymce script.

Add this in function,

```
script_url : '/assets/libs/tinymce/tinymce.min.js' //your javascript file path
```

i am not sure. but may be it will solve your porblem.

Answer (score 0):

Here might be your solution to use inline mode of tinymce to https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/multiple-editors/